# Grails Logback Plugin - How to separate stdout and stacktrace into 2 separate log files?

Tags: grails, logback

Using Log4j, we were able to configure two appenders with name 'stdout' and 
'stacktrace'  and redirects the logs to two different files. However, only 
stdout seems to be working with Logback plugin. Does anyone know how to get 
stacktrace working as well using Logback?

For example (I have also posted this in the grails mailing list but have not received any responses yet) :

```
logback = { 
   appenders { 
      rollingFile name: 'stdout', file: '/tmp/rolling.log', 
                  encoder: pattern(pattern: '%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n'), 
                  triggeringPolicy: new  SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(maxFileSize: 10*1024*1024), 
                  rollingPolicy: new FixedWindowRollingPolicy(fileNamePattern: '/tmp/rolling.%i.log.gz') 

      rollingFile name: 'stacktrace', file: '/tmp/rollingstacktrace.log', 
                  encoder: pattern(pattern: '%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n'), 
                  triggeringPolicy: new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(maxFileSize: 10*1024*1024), 
                  rollingPolicy: new FixedWindowRollingPolicy(fileNamePattern: '/tmp/rollingstacktrace.%i.log.gz') 
   } 

   //other logging code goes here................... 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Are you missing imports?

```
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
```

Comment: It wasn't the import issue. I didn't include my exact code in the example as I was using some variables for log directory path and custom pattern. The example code was from your documentation - just modified for the appender name 'stacktrace'. I tried again afresh after replacing my code with the example code, grails clean and it is working now. So, probably it was my mistake. Thanks for looking into this.